# Create Matrix of factors from data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to convert a factor data frame, to a factor matrix

But when I try the below code, the type of the matrix is still string

```
mydata=data.frame(f1=c("yes","yes","no","no"),f2=c("yes","no","no","yes"))
mydata[1:ncol(mydata)]=lapply(mydata[1:ncol(mydata)],factor)

mymatrix=as.matrix(mydata)

#this line didn't help (the matrix still string)
mymatrix=apply(mymatrix,FUN =factor,MARGIN = 2)
```

Comment: Matrices in R can generally be only one of the atomic types, so your choices are sort of only character or the integer codes underlying the factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will get you what you need?

```
mymatrix = matrix(mydata, ncol = 2)
str(mymatrix)
```

gives you

```
List of 2
$ : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 1 1
$ : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 1 1 2
- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 1 2
```

You would need to explain a bit more what you want to do to get more precise help.

Comment: That is exactly what I need, I should use matrix instead of as.matrix
Thanks

Comment: But something strange happens here, when I call  mydata[1,1] it returns "yes" , but matrix[1,1] returns the whole columns [1] yes yes no  no

Comment: Yes, mainly you get two lists this is why you get this result. Keep in mind that factors make sense only if you have a list. From (http://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html) "The factor stores the nominal values as a vector of integers in the range [ 1... k ] (where k is the number of unique values in the nominal variable), and an internal vector of character strings (the original values) mapped to these integers.". Is not a data type like integer or double. Maybe we could help you out more if you tell us what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want a matrix of "factors"?